# Count the occurrences of each value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

How to remove duplicate values from an array in PHP and count the occurrence of every element?
I have this array

- foo
- bar
- foo

I want the result to be in array like this

```
        value   freq

        ----    ----

        foo       2

        bar       1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so simple , php have function

```
$a=array("Cat","Dog","Horse","Dog");
    print_r(array_count_values($a));
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
Array ( [Cat] => 1 [Dog] => 2 [Horse] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 5):

You want [array_count_values()](http://php.net/array_count_values), followed by an [array_unique()](http://php.net/array_unique).

```
$arr = array('foo','bar','foo');
print_r(array_count_values($arr));

$arr = array_unique($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

gives:

```
Array ( [foo] => 2 [bar] => 1 )
Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar )
```

Comment: why need array_unique ? the array already unique after array_count_values

Comment: True.  I had it in my head that he would need to be using the counts separate from the unique values, but you're right, `array_count_values()` does give you a unique key listing, whereas array_unique gives you a unique value listing.  For ahmeds's purposes, he probably only needs `array_count_values()`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps (untested)

```
$freq = array();
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $freq[$val] = 0;
}
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $freq[$val]++;
}
```

Comment: Actually, Andrew's solution is beter. His is one pass... my head doesn't work that quick :'(

Comment: Scratch that. haim's sol'n pwns. array_count_values